# For some reason when I triple tap a TextInput, the tapped line isn't selected

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

I am using kivy's TextInput in a project. In the documentation they say that TextInput.on_triple_tap is selecting the whole tapped line.
But when I tripple tap a line in my text box, nothing is selected.

I tried even to make my own on_triple_tap function, but it didn't work either.

Am I missing something?

First example - this should work, but it doesn't

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class ManagerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TextInput(text='hello world')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ManagerApp().run()
```

second example - I tried to override the on_triple_tap, prints the 'reached' but doesn't select anything

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class ManagerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.ti = TextInput(text='hello world', 
on_triple_tap=self.my_triple_tap)
        return self.ti

    def my_triple_tap(self, ti):
        print 'reached'
        ti.select_all()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ManagerApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have at least one "line" of text in the `TextInput`. That means at least one `newline` character. Change:

```
class ManagerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TextInput(text='hello world')
```

to:

```
class ManagerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TextInput(text='hello world\n')
```

Comment: Ho wow that’s a solution I wouldn’t think about. It will work the same if I’m using multiline=False?